# Send data to Hardware and go to another webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to use a photon and by click on a button some data is sent to the photon via the cloud. However, at the same time I would like to go to another page as well. The problem is that when I try to press the button, it doesnt even go to the other page. Im not sure yet if the data is even being sent (haven't tested), but it should go to another page. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<input id="Memory Button" type="button" value="Memory Game" onclick="return myFunction1("setGame"),myFunction2()"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



function myFunction1(objButton)
{
    var deviceID = "1f0026001847353236343033";
    var accessToken = "edc90d3d0f4048681a946f75a7bbe221ad7e1110";
    var baseURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/";

    varname=objButton;
    requestURL= baseURL + deviceID + "/" + varName + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    $.post( requestURL, { params: varName , access_token: accessToken });
}

function myFunction2()
{
    window.location.href = 'http://twin-cities.umn.edu/';
}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just don't return anything from the inline handler, there's no receiver for the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, I changed the return but its still not going to the next page I have when I click the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using hardware through webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978682/using-hardware-through-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` should be `onclick="myFunction1('setGame');myFunction2()"` like

```
<input id="Memory Button" type="button" value="Memory Game" onclick="myFunction1('setGame');myFunction2()"/>
```

total

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<input id="Memory Button" type="button" value="Memory Game" onclick="myFunction1('setGame');myFunction2()"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



function myFunction1(objButton)
{
    var deviceID = "1f0026001847353236343033";
    var accessToken = "edc90d3d0f4048681a946f75a7bbe221ad7e1110";
    var baseURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/";

    varname=objButton;
    requestURL= baseURL + deviceID + "/" + varName + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    $.post( requestURL, { params: varName , access_token: accessToken });
}

function myFunction2()
{
    window.location.href = 'http://twin-cities.umn.edu/';
}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I added the changes, but its not going to the next page when clicking button.