# Using hardware through webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I am trying  to make a web page that, after the button for Memory game is clicked it will do two things:

1. It will set the cloud function I wrote in the hardware's code and act accordingly and
2. It will go to another web page entirely.

However, when I try to make it do this, it doesn't work. I am not sure if the hardware is even getting the correct message (haven't tested it yet) but I should be able to go to the next page. Through testing, it goes to the next page if the `$.post( requestURL, { params: thisGame, access_token: accessToken });` is commented out.

Please, any assistance is much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="Memory Button" type="button" value="Memory Game" onclick="myFunction1('Memory')"/>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            var deviceID = "device id";
            var accessToken = "access token";
            var baseURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/";
            var whichGame="setGame";

            function myFunction1(thisGame)
            {  
                var requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" +   whichGame + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;

                $.post( requestURL, { params: thisGame, access_token: accessToken });

                myFunction2();
            }

            function myFunction2()
            {
                window.location.href = 'http://twin-cities.umn.edu/';
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: You shouldn't change the window location until your get your callback from the `$.post`

Comment: Shouldn't `myFunction2 ` be a callback for your `$.post`? Your hardware wont receive anything if you forward before your `$.post` completes, and `post` is, I presume, asynchronous.

Comment: you are using a jquery function and you have not included the script as you have shown in the code. I hope that is not the case.

Comment: @user2507 which would an error in the console (OP not confirmed if errors or not)

Comment: @somethinghere if that were the case, it would still call myFunction2, ie navigate away (and the issue would be to do with the post rather than the redirect)

Comment: Im sorry everyone. I am kind of confused. Is it not going to the next page because there is an error with the post?

Comment: Because you didn't include jquery you get an error on the `.post`.  Then when you include jquery, you will get intermittant results because you change the page location before the async post is complete.

Comment: You should not post the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40961887/4202224) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40964887/4202224) again, try to make one as clear as possible

Answer (score 2):

Include the jquery cdn in the header like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And you may try using AJAX with the following code:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({                                                     
        url: yourURL,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("token", token_value);         //append token to header
        },
        error : function(response){                     //if something went wrong on server
            console.log(response);
            alert("Something went wrong. Please try later.");
        },
        success: function(response){
            //call the function you wanted to call here
        }
    });
```

Where 'data' is a stringified object containing all the data you want to send.

Comment: thank you! So, where does token go again? it says to append token to header

Comment: the token_value is the token variable here.

Comment: Thanks again So, is it the variable with ajax or is it my own access token for my hardware?

Comment: AJAX is just a function, it does not need any token to be used. It is a way of contacting a server without the need of reloading the page. When you contact a server, to distinguish between unauthenticated and authenticated requests, servers usually ask for a access_token. 
P.S: It is the token for your hardware.

Comment: Thank you! And is something went wrong was displayed, that would mean something happened somewhere on the hardware side.

Comment: Not always. If you are not sending the request properly then also it will turn into an error, but if your request is correct then the problem is on the other end for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
function myFunction1(thisGame)
{  
    var requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" +   whichGame + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;

    $.post( requestURL, { params: thisGame, access_token: accessToken });
      myFunction2();
}
```

to:

```
function myFunction1(thisGame)
{  
    var requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" +   whichGame + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;

    $.post( requestURL, { params: thisGame, access_token: accessToken })
      .done(myFunction2)
      .fail(function(){ alert('FAIL!'); });
}
```

And add this just after the `<html>` tag:

```
<head>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It still didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to include jquery on the page.

Comment: OMG! it went to the next page! OK, THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH. I was struggling and very confused. I am going to try to see if it makes #1 work as well. Thanks again!

Comment: So, just a last question, what will happen when fail is read?

Comment: It will alert you with the 'FAIL!' message.

Comment: Depends on the fail message.  If it returns an actual fail return code, then it will put up an alert.  If the return is a fail message, but the return code shows successful, then it will still redirect you.  You can catch it in the done function if you need to check the status.  It will pass the message as a parameter, so in your case, you need to have `myFunction2` take a parameter, and check it for the result, and do what you want to do with it in there. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more details.